# How to update Cordova Based App when new version is Available in AppStore?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, auto-update

I have Developed a Cordova Based Application which is published to Both IOS and Apple Store, I want users to get notified when there is a new version and allow users to update the app from App Store, Currently, I have tried few plugins but most of them are not working, Can someone help me how to Notify to Users for Update ?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this plugin ? https://github.com/AyogoHealth/cordova-plugin-update-notifier

> cordova-plugin-update-notifier This plugin provides a mechanism for
> showing an in-app notification when a new version of the app is
> available for download from the App Store or Play Store.
>
> For iOS, this uses the Siren library.
>
> For Android, this implements the Play Store In-App Update system.

Comment: There is no much documentation on how to use it :( 
Can you please share ?

Comment: There is everything you need? Set it up and it will show a notification when new version is available.

Comment: So I just need to install plugin ? No Configuration ?
There are two types of Updates, Flexible and Immediate. Where can I do configurations so I use Intermediate In App Update for my app ?

Comment: i'm not the maintainer of this repo. i'm suggestion you investigate this plugin since it's fairly new. Maybe get in touch with the dev?